# Is it possible to send the JS variable to parameter of the php function

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible the Javascript variable value to the php url parameter? please see following code and give a suggestion how to do this?
Html code:

```
foreach($rd as $data){
            echo "<tr><td>".$data[role_name]."</td><td>".$data[role_description]."</td><td><a href=".$this->action('edit', $data['role_id']).">Edit</a></td><td>".$ih->button_js(t('Delete'), "deleteRole('".$data['role_id']."')", 'left', 'error')."</td></tr>";
        }
```

in this code i call JS function deleteRole?():
script:

```
function deleteRole(myvar) {
    if (confirm('<?php echo $delConfirmJS ?>')) {
       location.href = "<?php echo $this->url('/role/add_role/', 'delete', 'myvar')?>";
    }
}
```

In my controller page i receive the myvar as string not the value? 
controller.php

```
public function delete($id){
    echo $id;
    exit;
    $delete = roleinfo::delete($id);
    $this->redirect('/role/add_role'); }
```

this echo print "myvar" only not a value? Please suggest me its write way or not ? else how to do this?

thanks
Kumar

Comment: I would suggest using AJAX to delete the database row.

Comment: thanks, how to use ajax? will you show the ajax sample code or demo

Answer (score 4):

You can't send or assign a JS variable directly to PHP function or variable, because of JS is a client side language and PHP is a server side language.

If you want to send you JS variable, one way is - you can send a ajax request to server, and then your variable will be available in php, and can use it.

Here is sample ajax format:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: base_path + '{file_name_where_you_want_to_receive_that_value}',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        myvar: myvar
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // when you provided url procedd the req. then success will call.

    }
})
```

And in [file_name_where_you_want_to_receive_that_value] assing that value to some variable and use it.

Comment: thanks, how to use the ajax request will you give any sample or demo code

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a form or smthg? I suppose the easiest way would be with a hidden field where you just modify the value via JS and send it to PHP with POST. Its not a clean or professional way, but easy to implement and does its job.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple AJAX request you can make is the following (using jQuery for simplicity, you can search for how to do an AJAX request without jQuery):

```
function deleteRole(myvar) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->url('/role/add_role/', 'delete', 'myvar')?>",
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $( this ).addClass( "done" );
    });
}
```

This will create a new request to the specified URL, and basically run the controller action. You will have the request response in the javascript variable data.

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).